# How to format and create a list

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have been trying to create a JSON(?) list for quite a while and I am having trouble not only formatting it but also understanding how it works. I currently have a code snippet as follows in JS:

```
var singularTerms = [
'square root',
'square',
'cube root',
'cube'
];
```

and I also have another list like this, and in case you were wondering what I was doing, I am creating a <strike>really unfinished</strike> random math equation creator. Just make sure to copy the code and paste into the console on any webpage. It doesn't work in JSFiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/eslota52/wd2vjxfo/
I'm trying to create a JSON list but with the random selector (`pickedTerm = singularTerms[Math.floor(Math.random() * singularTerms.length)];`) i'm using it doesn't work with a JSON list.
`var singularTerms = [ 'square root': '√' ];`, or something like that. Could anybody shed some light on me with this topic?

Comment: What you've coded there is a JavaScript **array**. When describing a problem with code, post the code **here** and explain what you *expect* it to do and what exactly is going wrong, along with any errors reported by the browser (or other relevant runtime).

Comment: what about JSON.stringify() https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: @MichaelPloeckinger what would be the point of that?

Comment: `[ 'square root': '√' ]` is simply not a valid JSON (not even a valid JS code). It should be `[{ "square root": "√" }]`

Comment: I don't know how to use that and I also don't think the code I'm using to randomly pick something from the string would work.

Comment: It works fine until I try adding a second value.

Comment: @Pointy dont know why I commented your comment :)